# How to send Email from Microsoft Access from Addresses stored in a query?

Tags: email, ms-access

I have a Table called PersonsContactDetails where I have two fields: ContactDetailType and ContactDetailValue. The first one stores the type of the email: "Personal Email", "Work Email", "Generic Email", the second Field stores the Email Address.

I am running a Query PersonalEmailList and WorkEmailList that not only store the Respective Emails Type, but Also CountryOfOrigin, City and Gender.

I would like to send an Email to all the contacts, depending on their country of Origin, City or Gender. I tried to Filter The QueryDataSheet and have a VBA loop with OpenRecordSet but I get "Type Mismatch Error", I understand that the OpendRecordSet works only with Data Tables.

How could I proceed to this solution, knowing that my point in all this, is to filter contacts' emails on my Query depending on their Country, City or Gender, and from there send an email (of course using the BCC) field.

Answer (score 0):

An easy enough way is to create a recordset from your table or query, like so:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

''If this is run from a form, it may suit to use recordsetclone, otherwise

Set db = CurrentDB
s = "SELECT PersonalEmail FROM PersonsContactDetails " _
  & "WHERE CountryOfOrigin = 'Tsort'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset

Do While Not rs.EOF
   If Not IsNull(rs!PersonalEmail) Then
      EmailList = ";" & rs!PersonalEmail
   End If

   rs.MoveNext
Loop

''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214075(v=office.12).aspx

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , , , Mid(EmailList, 2), "Test", "Hi", True
```